# What package is responsible for the functionality of the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, package-management

I'm attempting to forward [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/625837) bug report in Launchpad to the appropriate project, but I'm not sure which one that is. The issue is with the user's keyboard, and the issue is that some multi-key keyboard shortcuts are not being recognised if the user presses them in a certain order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer posted by htorque helped with the particular bug report, and the bug report linked to by htorque reveals that `xorg-server` is responsible for keyboard input, along with the management of most other input devices. More information on the X Window System can be found at it's [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).

Comment: Maybe it's a Natty only thing, but there's no such package...

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the result of [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/control-center/+bug/36812) (I can reproduce the behavior from the report you linked to).  Its description contains all the necessary information to find a proposed patch, which probably will find its way into Ubuntu 11.04 (see comment #119 from Bryce Harrington).

As a workaround, you could change the keybinding to switch layouts via:

- `System > Preferences > Keyboard` , then
- `Layouts > Other Options... > Layout Switching > Key(s) to change layout` :

  [image]